# Validation of non-input field in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following piece of code:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="ui message">
        <p> {{ ctrl.someValueFetchedFromDatabase}} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to attach some validation to this `<div>`.  I mean some logical condition (depending on values in controller) which is checked during 
submiting form (I have binded function in conroller with this submit button).

The result of validating should be message, almost exactly the same as here: 
[image]

To sum up: I am searching for a way to validate non-input field in some specific way.

Comment: angular 1 or 2+ ?

Comment: can you be a bit more clean on what the problem is

Comment: non-input field..? are you refering to <p> tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is:

```
<div class="field">
    <div ng-if="ctrl.resultOfTheValidation" class="ui message">
        <p> {{ ctrl.someValueFetchedFromDatabase}} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `ctrl.resultOfTheValidation` would have a true/false value. I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

set name for your form  and input and set rquired attribute for your input and set novalidate attribute to your form.

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="ui message" ng-show="{{formName.inputName.$error.required && formName.inputName.$dirty }}">
        <p> {{ ctrl.someValueFetchedFromDatabase}} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```